# Identify this RCD or RCBO

Tags: circuit-breaker, rcd

Here's a close up as requested. Apologies for it being a bit fuzzy.
Is there any reason why this shouldn't be used to protect a dedicated 4mm TPS circuit for a 3kW spa pool?
Thanks for your help.
[image]
Can anyone tell me if this is includes a circuit breaker (20A I'd assume) or if it's just an RCD?

[image]

Comment: Could you add a close-up of the little diagram?

Answer (score 3):

**FI/LS** is the German abbreviation for [*Fehlerstrom-Leitungsschutzschalter*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fehlerstrom-Schutzschalter), which means it's a *residual current circuit breaker*.

Hager: [Fehler­strom-Lei­tungs­schutz­schalter FI-LS (RCBO)](https://hager.com/de-ch/katalog/energieverteilung-i-schutz-steuern-melden-messen/fehlerstrom-leitungsschutzschalter-fi-ls-rcbo-)

---

> Are you also able to tell me which way around line and load are (top/bottom?)

As [@Kartman](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/269567/kartman) commented:

> 1,3 are the input, 2,4 the load. The diagram shows the test button across the load terminals.

Comment: Thanks very much Velvel! That's really helpful. Are you also able to tell me which way around line and load are (top/bottom?) Trying to find a way to upload a better close up of diagram for Jonathanjo.

Comment: 1,3 are the input, 2,4 the load. The diagram shows the test button across the load terminals.

Comment: Are you sure, the symbol doesn't have the thermal-magnetic [squigles](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Circuit_breaker_symbols#/media/File:Disjoncteur_bipolaire.png)?